# INSPIRE literature for the common man

Tags: inspire

As a GIS Coordinator I am constantly amazed at how difficult it is to comprehend the literature produced by the European Commission regarding the Inspire directive. If this is hard work for people who work full time in the profession how can anyone expect anyone working on the peripheries of GIS to understand it´s demands? With this in mind, does anyone know of any literature describing INSPIRE for the common man? I saw an "INSPIRE for dummies" pdf once which had great reviews but it was unfortunately in french. If anyone has something similar from a good source it would be very helpful. I am of the opinion that INSPIRE doesn´t have to be difficult. It has just become too complicated through bureaucracy.

Comment: INSPIRE for dummies in English (after the first slide) http://www.slideshare.net/libertic/inspire-for-dummies

Comment: "implementation of INSPIRE in the UK" http://data.gov.uk/location/guidance_and_tools

Comment: http://georezo.net/blog/inspire/files//home/georezo/data/prod/blog/wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/2009/10/Inspire_pour_les_neophytes1.pdf was the associated text as far as I can see....this is what I wanted to read in english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OSGEO wiki](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/INSPIRE) has a nice (with their own opinion) summary on the main INSPIRE components (see an subset below), as well as useful links. The first step is to identify the component that is the most relevant in your case.

> **Metadata**. Well, we know that Metadata is data and so on. Intriguing
>   topic. The current interpretation of INSPIRE clobbered metadata long
>   enough with ISO profiles to almost kill it.
>
> **Network Services**. Performance, uptime, bindings, etc. & still under
>   work.
>
> **Discovery Services**. Probably something like Catalog Services but it is
>   as yet unclear why they should: ...making it possible to search for
>   spatial data sets and services on the basis of the content of the
>   corresponding metadata and to display the content of the metadata
>
> **View Services**. Straight forward: Digital maps served through WMS 1.3 /
>   ISO 19128. ...making it possible, as a minimum, to display, navigate,
>   zoom in/out, pan, or overlay viewable spatial data sets and to display
>   legend information and any relevant content of metadata;
>
> **Download Services**. Straight forward: Digital data served through WFS 2.0 / ISO 19142) -> see this discussion ...enabling copies of spatial data sets,
>   or parts of such sets, to be downloaded and, where practicable,
>   accessed directly;
>
> **Transformation Services**. Rubbish. The original idea was that a web
>   service would be able to transform existing data by members stated
>   on-the-fly for further processing. This is usually done offline in the
>   basement on number crunchers. ...enabling spatial data sets to be
>   transformed with a view to achieving interoperability Services ...
>   allowing spatial data services to be invoked. (I never really got this
>   one?)
>
> **Data and Service Sharing**. Licenses, copyright, all the fun stuff that
>   prevents us from using data in our software.
>
> **Data Specification**. The tricky bit is the harmonization of data that
>   is need prior to setting up the actual service. This currently
>   requires lots of transformations with GML 3.2.1 (and not enough
>   software packages supporting 3.2.1 does not help either) Reporting and
>   Monitoring. This is more domain specific to EU public administrations.
>   Not clear yet whether any software will be involved in this. But the
>   monitoring services will be of help to control things.

Taking this further.

Network services are any service ~ CSW, WFS, SOS, WPS...

A discovery service is a service that aids discovery of data sets and services, for example  a CSW.

A view service is a service that permits viewing of the data, for example WMS and WMTS.

A download service is a service that allows data to be downloaded, for example that's WFS, WCS, and ATOM

A transformation service is one that allows some transformation of a data set, such as WCPS and WPS.

The data specifications are guidance that tell data providers how to supply data in a fashion that conforms to the data specified in the Annexes, according to the legislation.  That is, if you are a data provider and you have in scope data they tell you how to supply data in a way that means you comply with the law.  You may find alternative ways of supplying data that complies with the law, but you'll need to to comprehensively understand the legislation...